# sqlite: how to create a table and import a CSV file into that table from a shell script?

Tags: shell, sqlite

I try to emulate this tutorial

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

(basically, create a new DB and create a new table in that DB from a CSV file)

using a shell script but am stuck on the first few commands.

I think I can create a new db in a non-interactive script like this

```
sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
```

but how do I then set the mode to csv? I am having problem with the syntax.

I have found a few examples here on SE for Python and PHP but they seem to use built-in functions in those languages rather than the sqlite prompt.

Comment: What sort of problem are you having exactly? Seems pretty straightforward... you want a `.mode` line and a `.import` line.

Comment: @glibdud The main task is to automate creating a DB from a CSV file. The problem I have is that I need some syntax examples that can be used from an sh "prompt" rather than an sqlite prompt.

Comment: You just need the `.mode` line, followed by the `.import` line, followed by `EOF` to close the heredoc.

Comment: I know but exactly how do I write these lines in a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 <<EOF
.mode csv
.import file.csv tbl
.save file.db
EOF
```